# fragment text appearing in toolbar

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-studio, navigation-drawer

I'm trying to get a sliding drawer set up.  I want the text to appear in the main body of the activity, but instead it's appearing inside of the toolbar, and it only says This is fragment 2, regardless of whether I pulled up the fragment that's supposed to say This is fragment 1 or This is fragment 2.

How can I make it pull up the proper fragment, instead of always fragment 2, and how can I make the toolbar opaque, with text appearing under it instead of in it.

[image: screenshot of when I first open the app]

[image: screenshot of when I click either of the fragments in the nav drawer]

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
              tools:context="me.paxana.alerta.MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="8dp"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/main_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/lv_sliding_menu"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:layout_gravity="start" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package me.paxana.alerta;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

import com.parse.ParseUser;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import butterknife.Bind;
import butterknife.ButterKnife;
import me.paxana.alerta.adapter.SlidingMenuAdapter;
import me.paxana.alerta.fragment.Fragment1;
import me.paxana.alerta.fragment.Fragment2;
import me.paxana.alerta.fragment.Fragment3;
import me.paxana.alerta.model.ItemSlideMenu;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private List<ItemSlideMenu> listSliding;
    private SlidingMenuAdapter adapter;
    private ListView listViewSliding;
    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    private android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;
    private Toolbar mToolbar;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);


        ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
             if (currentUser == null) {
                navigateToLogin();
            }

        else {
                Log.i(TAG, currentUser.getUsername());
            }

        listViewSliding = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv_sliding_menu);
        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        listSliding = new ArrayList<>();
        //add item for sliding list
        listSliding. add(new ItemSlideMenu(R.drawable.ic_action_settings, "Settings"));
        listSliding.add(new ItemSlideMenu(R.drawable.ic_action_about, "About"));
        listSliding.add(new ItemSlideMenu(R.drawable.ic_logout_black_48dp, "Log Out"));
        adapter = new SlidingMenuAdapter(this, listSliding);
        listViewSliding.setAdapter(adapter);


        //display icon to open/close slider
        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        assert getSupportActionBar() != null;
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        //item selected
        listViewSliding.setItemChecked(0, true);
        //close menu
        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(listViewSliding);
        //handle on item click
        listViewSliding.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                if (position == 2) {
                    ParseUser.logOut();
                    navigateToLogin();
                } else {

                    //replace fragment
                    replaceFragment(position);
                    //item selected
                    listViewSliding.setItemChecked(position, true);
                    //close menu
                    drawerLayout.closeDrawer(listViewSliding);
                }
            }

        });

        actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, R.string.drawer_opened, R.string.drawer_closed) {
            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };

        drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);

    }

    private void navigateToLogin() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if(actionBarDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }

        int itemId = item.getItemId();
        if (itemId == R.id.action_logout) {
            ParseUser.logOut();
            navigateToLogin();

        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }
//create method replace fragment
    private void replaceFragment(int pos) {
        android.support.v4.app.Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (pos) {
            case 0:
                fragment = new Fragment1();
                    break;
            case 1:
                fragment = new Fragment2();
                break;
            case 2:
                fragment = new Fragment3();
                break;
            default:
                fragment = new Fragment1();
                break;
        }
        if(null != fragment) {
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.main_content, fragment);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved one part of this issue, though I'm not certain I used best practices.  I added padding to the top of main_content in a size of "?attr/actionBarSize"

But it's still only displaying This is Fragment 2, regardless of which fragment I'm trying to select.

Comment: aaand i found the other problem.  a shitty little typo in my fragment itself.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the content below the toolbar, you can wrap toolbar and content in one layout as:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/main_content"
        android:background="#8000ff00"
        >
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Besides, if you are using Android Studio, creating Navigation Drawer Activity through the wizard is the best way to ensure that everything works properly.

Comment: how `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"`  would be applied here since you are using linearLayout?

Comment: a lot of the things in my mainactivity class rely on the layout being DrawerLayout

Comment: @k0sh, I agree android:layout_alignParentTop="true" not effect